# Excessive number of connections between replica set members

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I have a sharded mongodb database having three shards (replica sets), each has three replica set members, hosted on Linode cloud.

```
shards:
    {  "_id" : "s0",  "host" : "s0/mongo0.mongo.net:27100,mongo1.mongo.net:27101,mongo2.mongo.net:27102" }
    {  "_id" : "s1",  "host" : "s1/mongo0.mongo.net:27111,mongo1.mongo.net:27110,mongo2.mongo.net:27112" }
    {  "_id" : "s2",  "host" : "s2/mongo0.mongo.net:27121,mongo1.mongo.net:27122,mongo2.mongo.net:27120" }
```

The shard 's0' has primary replica on `mongo0.mongo.net:27100` and its also a primary shard of one collection which is sharded.

It's logs shows huge number of connections between the other two members (above 70 connections).  While the primary members of other two shards have 8 to 9 connections with their secondary members.

The question is, Is it normal to have such number of connections? Why is there such high number of connections? I started the shards by default configurations provided in the mongo docs.

I became aware if this by an email from Linode saying:

```
Your Linode, linodeXXXXXX (linodeXXXXXX), has exceeded the bandwidth quota threshold for notification.  It has used 3265.2555 GB of 4000 or 81.6%.
```

With peak outbound transfer rate of 255 Mbps!!, which IMO happened due to huge amount of read operations.

I apologize if this is not a relevant question for SO, but i did not find any other place for asking this.

[LOGS are pasted here](http://pastebin.com/3kHAmn0i).

Comment: Serverfault is a better place really though the high number of connections might actually be coming from your application because they are read induced and I am guessing your app has slaveOkay etc set

Comment: @Sammaye There is NodeJs application which communicates with this db. which has `setInterval()` loop for reading count of rows and return the newly inserted row. This preforms two queries every 5 seconds, one for count and second for retrieving new latest rows.

Comment: NodeJS itself will hold 5 connections per process open for connection pooling, how many NodeJS processes do you have running at a time? Of course it is not actually nodejs connecting to the replicas, it is the mongos, but I believe the mongos also does connection pooling

Comment: @Sammaye currently there are 3 node processes that inserts data, and one other node app [here](http://66.175.213.221:6010/) that mentioned above. All communicating via same mongos.